# Cannot add 4 numbers to mat opencv

Tags: opencv, matrix

I created a mat object in opencv , dimension Nx4 , in which I want to put N coordinates.
    `[Px Py 1 0]` 
    `[Py Px 0 1]`

For this I wrote the following code : 
     `vector<Point2f> features1 , features2;`
     `Mat features_1;`
     `for(int i = 0 , j = 0; i < feature1.size() ; ++i , j+=2)
    {
      features_1.at<Vec3d>(j) = {feature1[i].x , feature1[i].y , 1 , 0};
      features_1.at<Vec3d>(j) = {feature1[i].y , -feature1[i].x , 0 , 1};
    }`
But at the first line of the loop I get the following error : 
`cv::Matx<_Tp, m, n>::Matx(_Tp, _Tp, _Tp, _Tp) [with _Tp = double; int m = 3; int n = 1]: Assertion channels >= 4' failed.`

How can I solve this?

Comment: Your code doesn't come close to compiling for me, let alone provide a means to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's probably easier to push_back() single elements to a Mat, and later do a reshape().

this will make a 2*N x 4 Mat:

```
vector<Point2f> features1 , features2;
Mat features_1;
for(size_t i=0; i<feature1.size() ; ++i) 
{ 
    features_1.push_pack(feature1[i].x);
    features_1.push_pack(feature1[i].y);
    features_1.push_pack(1);
    features_1.push_pack(0);

    features_1.push_pack(feature2[i].y);
    features_1.push_pack(feature2[i].x);
    features_1.push_pack(0);
    features_1.push_pack(1);
}
features_1 = features_1.reshape(1,4); // or reshape(1,features1.size()*2); //for 4xN*2
```

Comment: But I want a single Mat object and as it is I have too many points to put it in separate Mat objects.

Answer (score 0):

Where you wrote `<Vec3d>`, did you mean `<Vec4d>`?

Your code is not close to correct, but here is a minimal example of how your desired result can be achieved (if you don't have C++11, just use an old style iterator in the loop)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
using namespace cv;   

int main()
{
    vector<Point2f> feature1;
    feature1.push_back(Point2f(1.0f, 2.0f));
    feature1.push_back(Point2f(3.0f, 4.0f));

    Mat features_1;

    for(auto p : feature1) 
    { 
        features_1.push_back(Vec4d(p.x, p.y , 1 , 0));
        features_1.push_back(Vec4d(p.y, -p.x , 0, 1));
    }

    // At this point the mat is (N, 1, CV_64FC4)
    // Reshape if you want  (N, 4, CV_64FC1);
    features_1 = features_1.reshape(1,4);

    cout << features_1;
}
```

This output of this is:

```
[1, 2, 1, 0;
 2, -1, 0, 1;
 3, 4, 1, 0;
 4, -3, 0, 1]
```

However, if the `features_1` is already allocated and you can't just use push_back, apart from releasing the mat, you could do this (assuming `features_1.isContinuous()` is true):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
using namespace cv;


int main()
{
    vector<Point2f> feature1;
    feature1.push_back(Point2f(1.0f, 2.0f));
    feature1.push_back(Point2f(3.0f, 4.0f));

    Mat features_1(2 * feature1.size(), 4, CV_64FC1);

    Vec4d* ptr = features_1.ptr<Vec4d>(0);
    for(auto p : feature1) 
    { 
        *ptr++ = Vec4d(p.x, p.y , 1 , 0);
        *ptr++ = Vec4d(p.y, -p.x , 0, 1);
    }

    cout << features_1 << endl;
}
```

The above produces the same result as the previous version.

If there is any possibility in the above example that `features_1.isContinuous()` is false,  you can use an iterator to scan `features_1`:

```
    auto ptr = features_1.begin<double>();
    for(auto p : feature1) 
    {   
        *ptr++ = p.x;
        *ptr++ = p.y;
        *ptr++ = 1;
        *ptr++ = 0;

        *ptr++ = p.y;
        *ptr++ = -p.x;
        *ptr++ = 0;
        *ptr++ = 1;    
    }
```